# How to modify list view to make a from-to view (FullCalendar)

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm looking to display a list with grouped date (ie: BeginDate - EndDate). Here the javascript that call fullCalendar.

```js
    var calLink = $('#calendar-link');
    calLink.fullCalendar({
        locale: 'en-US',
        height: 'auto',
        header: false,
        lazyFetching: false,
        themeSystem: 'bootstrap4',
        displayEventTime: false,
        displayEventEnd: true,
        nextDayThreshold: '01:00:00',
        defaultView: 'listTwoYears',
        eventSources: [
            {
                url: calLink.data('url'),
                type: 'GET',
                data: {},
                error: function () {
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(data);
                }
            }
        ],
        views: {
            listTwoYears: {
                eventOrder: 'title',
                type: 'list',
                duration: { days: 730 },
                buttonText: 'list'
            }
        }
    });
```

Here the expected result:

```
2019-01-18 to 2019-01-20
Event 1

2019-01-19 to 2019-01-20
Event 2

2019-01-20
Event 3
```

[Require display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyAKn.png)

But this what I have now (the normal list behaviour)  :

```
2019-01-18
Event 1

2019-01-19
Event 1
Event 2

2019-01-20
Event 1
Event 2
Event 3
```

[Current display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WelN1.png)

The list is made using this json:

```js
[
    {
        "title":"Event 1",
        "description":"Desc. Event 1",
        "start":"2019-01-18 12:00:00",
        "end":"2019-01-20 18:00:00",
        "allDay":false,
        "editable":false,
        "startEditable":false,
        "durationEditable":false,
        "overlap":false
    },
    {
        "title":"Event 2",
        "description":"Desc. Event 2",
        "start":"2019-01-19 12:00:00",
        "end":"2019-01-20 18:00:00",
        "allDay":false,
        "editable":false,
        "startEditable":false,
        "durationEditable":false,
        "overlap":false
    },
    {
        "title":"Event 3",
        "description":"Desc. Event 3",
        "start":"2019-01-20 12:00:00",
        "end":"2019-01-20 18:00:00",
        "allDay":false,
        "editable":false,
        "startEditable":false,
        "durationEditable":false,
        "overlap":false
    }

]
```

I tried lot of way looking in the documentation and searching the web.

Comment: since we can't see the event JSON you're generating it's quite hard to help you. Can you provide that `data` please?

Comment: @ADyson sorry about that. Didn't think it really mater in this case. But you're right.

Comment: Ok thanks, I see. I just wanted to check there was not some problem with the data.

Comment: So, to be clear, you are specifically talking about this in the context of the "list" type of view, yes? If so, then unfortunately what you want is not really possible using the existing software - the view is designed to output one block of entries per day. If you wanted some significantly different presentation in the way you've described then you would need to write a [custom view using JavaScript](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js) - but be aware that that is not a simple task. I suggest that you consider how essential this requirement really is before you proceed with that.

Comment: This is the format used for 20 years. And did receives request to go back with this format from around 10% of the users. And that's a lot.

Comment: IMHO familiarity (i.e. "we always do it this way") is not necessarily a good reason by itself for creating a feature. Instead, asking what business value it adds (vs the default output) would be a better question. Does it genuinely increase understanding of the data and reduce mistakes, and/or save the users a significant amount of time and effort in some task which relies on this data? If not then it's probably not worth the significant overhead of creating (and then re-testing and maintaining every time there's a new fullCalendar release) the custom view code.

Comment: I do understand this. But, in this case it's WAY better way of displaying the data. As an exemple, displaying a vacation for someone. It's from day X to day Y, then next, will be day N to day N2.  That's why usually the data is display in a calendar. But in some case, we display next activities for one group, what will never overlap, and never more that one by day.

Comment: Just add images so you can compare. You'll see, it's way easier to understand as activity are from date x to y (none stop)

Comment: If the activities never overlap then maybe what you actually need is just a boring old HTML list or table, and forget about calendar concepts altogether. It would be much simpler to implement than customising a fullCalendar view, even once you add in some ability to filter it etc.

Comment: Yes, but I also display calendars.

Comment: Nothing stopping you having both, based on the same source data, and showing/hiding each UI element as needed. Use your imagination a bit.